# Several iframe reload after 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page with several iframes and I need a script that reloads the iframes after 30 seconds. Until now I only found scripts that works for only iframe and the other dont get refreshed. Is there a way to reload several at the same time?

Edit: no time out needed

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(refreshiframe, 5000);
});

function refreshiframe() {
    $('#testframe').attr('src', $('#testframe').attr('src'));
}
```

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('iframe')].forEach(i => i.contentWindow.location.reload());`

Comment: Can you post what you've already tried?  **[ask]**

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
setInterval(refreshiframe, 5000);
});
function refreshiframe() {
$('#testframe').attr('src', $('#testframe').attr('src'));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<iframe id="testframe" src="http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com" width="350px" height="350px"></iframe>
</div>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Reload all `iframes`

```
let iFrames = document. getElementsByTagName('iframe');

for (let i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++){
  iFrames[i].src = iFrames[i].src;
}
```

Reload several `iframes` by class

```
let iFrames = document. getElementsByClassName('element-class');

for (let i = 0; i < iFrames.length; i++){
  iFrames[i].src = iFrames[i].src;
}
```

Reload one `iframe` by id

```
let iFrame = document.getElementById('element-id');
iFrame.src = iFrame.src;
```

Comment: Where do I edit the lengt 3000 where the 0 is for 30 seconds? and the class="element-class" goes into the iframe or a div?

Comment: @Hardi, I have a [working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samlegros/s7xqo1j0/) that reloads all the `iframes` and a certain amount of time. It has commented code to help walk through what's going on there. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Great, but still in my code it only works on one if add a class to several iframes. Also it should not have a timeout. It should continuously refresh.

Comment: If you need it to refresh, on line 9 of the JSFiddle, replace swap out `setTimeout` with `setInterval`. This will have it loop every 3 seconds, rather than have it fire once after waiting 3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really simple.

```
function refreshiFrames(selectors){
    //selectors is an array, it could be --  var selectors = ["#abc",".xyz"];  to get all the iframes that have Id "abc" or class "xyz"

    for(let i =0; i<selectors.length; i++){
        let iframes = document.querySelectorAll(selectors[i]);
        for (let j =0; j<iframes.length; j++){
             iframes[j].src = iframes[j].src;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't ask for a reload every 30 seconds - it should be `setTimeout()` unless it's clarified otherwise.

Comment: He didn't specify. So yeah it's setTimeout if he only needs a refresh once.

Comment: Is it possible only refresh only specific iframes with an id or name tag?